# MinGW exe reports libgcc_s_seh-1.dll not found even with -static-libgcc

Tags: cmake, mingw, cross-compiling, mingw32, boost-program-options

I'm cross compiling boost::program_options on Linux for Windows using CMake. In CMake I specified

```
set(Boost_LIBRARIES /usr/local/win64/lib/libboost_program_options.dll)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/win64/incldue)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(main.exe -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The generated .exe file runs OK on Windows when the first line uses static boost, i.e. libboost_program_options.a. However, when I want to use dynamic boost (in the above code), running the exe on Windows reports missing libgcc_s_seh-1.dll. Why is it looking for it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

> The generated .exe file runs OK on Windows when the first line uses static boost, i.e. libboost_program_options.a. However, when I want to use dynamic boost (in the above code), running the exe on Windows reports missing libgcc_s_seh-1.dll. Why is it looking for it anyway?

You've implicitly answered your own question, here: `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll` is a GCC runtime DLL. Dynamic boost wasn't compiled with `-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc`, so it depends on `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`. **You will have to recompile dynamic boost with these flags.**

Comment: So it's the dynamic boost that's looking for libgcc_s_seh-1.dll. How can I solve this problem here?

Comment: Build boost also with `-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc`

Comment: @BrechtSanders -- Yup. I thought that was implied in my answer... I'll make it more explicit.